# Google Sheets - Using regex to pull all data from a multi-line json file

Tags: google-sheets

I have to extract data from bulk json files. The json files come in 2 different formats, either 1 block of continuous text, or a list of text of 20-30 lines.

I'm using the following code:

`=IMPORTREGEX(E3,"(.*')")`

(note that I have a script running which supports this formula)

This works completely fine for the first format of json files, the 1 continuous block. But for the json files which are in list format, it only returns the first line.

How can I make it return all the data from the entire list? (Ideally in a single cell, as if it was 1 continuous block of data, same as the other json format).

Thanks!

Comment: can you give us a copy of the spreadsheet ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the spreadsheet as it has sensitive information.

Comment: I can provide an example of the json file I'm trying to import here @MikeSteelson:

https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmPF31vU6VXHD4M9Wqaei2zM8zxR78Rh9uaXTTgUUTFWQz/50.json

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse a json, try ...

```
// mike.steelson
let result = []; 
function getAllDataJSON() {
  var source = `{
  "dna": "46918e86a302f011f8c01f5164ca8ba7c0085780",
  "name": "#50",
  "description": "The limited collection of 5555 lazy bunnies who lost their homes to a wildfire and are now looking for owners who can take them to the moon!",
  "image": "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/QmT7wNzMbUNn4XgZSZD6fVgvP4xCjz9myWgrQrdQXfhYmG/50.png",
  "edition": 50,
  "date": 1637079661255,
  "attributes": [
    {
      "trait_type": "Background",
      "value": "Purple"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Skins",
      "value": "Imperial"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Eyes",
      "value": "Bewildered"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Mouths",
      "value": "Confused"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Clothes",
      "value": "Hoodie"
    },
    {
      "trait_type": "Ear Rings",
      "value": "Burning Stars"
    }
  ],
  "compiler": "HashLips Art Engine"
}`
  var data = JSON.parse(source)
  getAllData(eval(data),'data')
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  sh.getRange(1, 1, result.length, result[0].length).setValues(result);
}
function getAllData(obj,id) {
  const regex = new RegExp('[^0-9]+');
  for (let p in obj) {
    var newid = (regex.test(p)) ? id + '["' + p + '"]' : id + '[' + p + ']';
    if (obj[p]!=null){
      if (typeof obj[p] != 'object' && typeof obj[p] != 'function'){
        result.push([newid, obj[p]]);
      }
      if (typeof obj[p] == 'object') {
        getAllData(obj[p], newid );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, getting the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null (line 7).

Comment: Here is the script:


`function importRegex(url, regexInput) {
  var output = '';
  var fetchedUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  if (fetchedUrl) {
    var html = fetchedUrl.getContentText();
    if (html.length && regexInput.length) {
      output = html.match(new RegExp(regexInput, 'i'))[1];
    }
  }
  // Grace period to not overload
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  return output;
}`


I guess the error is referring to that

Comment: Strangely that error seems to apply to my original formula now as well, was working fine earlier!

Comment: If you want to parse a json, use an appropriate script like this one (i have updates my answer). Replace the source by `var fetchedUrl = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {muteHttpExceptions: true}); var source = fetchedUrl.getContentText();`